# How do I find the meaning of a particular fringe marking in emacs (c mode especially)?

Tags: emacs, c-mode

There are various fringe markings that show up in c-mode in emacs (24.4.1).  By inference I've figured out that the yellow >> is a warning of some sort, whereas the red >> is an error.  But I'd like to be able to know explicitly what the c-mode syntax evaluator thinks is actually the reason why it's marked that line in the fringe.  How do I find this out?  I've tried clicking on the fringe.  Is there some command I can run when placing my cursor on that line?

Comment: The standard/default `c-mode` is a major-mode that does nothing special to the fringes as far as I am aware.  Do you have a minor-mode running that might account for special fringe markings, e.g., `flymake` or something like that?  Do you also have a particular theme active that modifies the default colors of a minor-mode that creates fringe markings?  `M-x describe-mode RET`

Comment: I'm using prelude which enables a bunch of stuff.  Hmm on closer look it appears that it uses cc-mode (http://cc-mode.sourceforge.net/) not c-mode, oh, and there it is, FlyC that's what's doing it.  http://www.flycheck.org/en/latest/user/error-interaction.html Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fringe marks for any line can be listed with `(fringe-marks-at-pos)`.  For more information on that function, see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Fringe-Bitmaps.html#index-fringe_002dbitmaps_002dat_002dpos).